# Is it possible to work with a list of generic values with different type parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types, functional-programming

I want to achieve the following:

1. There is a list of strings I need to process.
2. There are several different kinds of these processors, each of which knows which part of the string to read.
3. I need to work in 2 phases: first, processors need to see each input string to build processor-specific data; second, each input string is processed by each of the processors, and the resulting strings are combined into one.

It's easy to do it in a mutable way: there's a common base class for all processors, the different kinds of data they aggregate is encapsulated in the concrete implementations; the interface consists of just 2 functions --- "look at input string and build internal data" and "process input string using your internal data."

As I am writing it in Scala, I am wondering if there exists a pure functional approach. The problem is that now the base trait for these processors is parameterized by the type of their internal data, and there doesn't seem to be a way to have a list of processors of different kinds.

This problem can be demonstrated on a simpler case: say I'd stick with the mutable approach, but for some reason have parameterized the type of what the processor takes from the string:

```
trait F[V] {
  def get(line: String) : V
  def aggregate(value: V)
  def process(value: V) : String
}

class F1 extends F[Int] // ...
class F2 extends F[HashMap[Int, Int]] // ...

for (s <- List("string1", "string2"); 
  f <- List(new F1(), new F2()) 
{
  f.aggregate(f.get(s)); // Whoops --- doesn't work   
}
```

It doesn't work because `f.get(s)` returns `Any`. Looks like I need to express in Scala's type system that `List(new F1(), new F2())` contains `F[?]` that are different but consistent in that if I take an element of that list, it has some concrete value of its type parameter, and `f.get(s)` is of that type, which should be accepted by `f.aggregate()`.

In the end, I would like to have something like this (with omissions because I don't get how to do it):

```
trait F[D] {
  def initData : D
  def aggregate(line: String, data: D) : D
  def process(line: String, data: D) : String
}

class F1 extends F[Int] // ...
class F2 extends F[HashMap[Int, Int]] // ...

// Phase 1
// datas --- List of f.initData, how to?
for (s <- List("string1", "string2")) {
  for (f <- List(new F1(), new F2()) {
    // let fdata be f's data
    // update fdata with f.aggregate(s, fdata)
  }
}

// Phase 2
for (s <- List("string1", "string2")) {
  for (f <- List(new F1(), new F2()) {
    // let fdata be f's data
    // for all fs, concatenate f.process(s, fdata) into an output string
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this task solvable in pure functional way in Scala?
2. Is this task solvable in other functional languages?
3. This situation looks like quite a general one. Is there a name for it I could search?
4. Where is the best place to read about it, assuming little to no background on theory of types and functional programming languages?

Comment: Can you extend your second example? It's not evident in which order do you want to apply your functions.

As I understood, you want your project specific data calculated like this:

    d1 = process(aggregate("s2", aggregate("s1", f1.initData)) ?

But how then strings should be processed using this data?

    process("s1", d1), process("s2", d2) ?

Or something other?

Comment: This sounds like a very straightforward two-stage `map`ping pipeline. Or `map` followed by `reduce`... I think there's a name for that...

Comment: @alno: sorry, the code in the question was quite unclear. I clarified it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you may use [abstract types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/105) instead of generics, so:

```
trait F {
  type D
  def initData: D
  def aggregate(line: String, data: D): D
  def process(line: String, data: D): String
}

class F1 extends F { type D = Int } // ...
class F2 extends F { type D = Map[Int, Int] } // ...

val strings = List("string1", "string2")
for (f <- List(new F1(), new F2())) {
  val d = strings.foldLeft(f.initData) { (d, s) => f.aggregate(s, d) }

  for (s <- strings)
    f.process(s, d)
}
```

Don't sure, if I undrestood correct order of operation, but it may be a starting point.

Comment: Sorry for misguiding question; I hope it's more clear now that I've edited it. Alas, it's not the solution: I want to traverse `strings` only once in Phase 1 and once in Phase 2. You see, if I'm going functional, I need to store my data outside of the function, or update the function itself; but for that, I need to have a list either of `Any` or of `F[Any]`. How to work with such a list is what intrigues me.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Just noticed, that my former solution was overly verbose, consing up a temporary data structure without any need.

I am not sure, what you mean with "purely functional". The following solution (if it is a solution to your problem) is "purely functional", as it has no side effects except the final `println` call in `main`.

Note, that the `List[F[_]](...)` is important, since otherwise, the compiler will infer a very specific internal type for the elements of the list, which doesn't go well with the `aggregateAndProcess` function.

```
trait F[D] {

    type Data = D  // Abbreviation for easier copy+paste below. Does not
                       // contribute to the actual solution otherwise

    def initData: Data
    def aggregate(line: String, data: Data) : Data
    def process(line: String, aggData: Data): String
}

class F1 extends F[Int] {
    def initData: Data = 1
    def aggregate(line: String, data: Data) : Data = data + 1
    def process(line: String, aggData: Data): String = line + "/F1" + aggData
}

class F2 extends F[Boolean] {
    def initData: Data = false
    def aggregate(line: String, data: Data) : Data = !data
    def process(line: String, aggData: Data): String = line + "/F2" + aggData
}

object Main {

    private def aggregateAndProcess[T](line: String, processor: F[T]): String =
        processor.process(line, processor.aggregate(line, processor.initData))

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val r = for {
            s <- List("a", "b")
            d <- List[F[_]](new F1, new F2)
        } yield
            aggregateAndProcess(s, d)

        println(r.toList)
    }
}
```

Note, though, that I am still unsure as to what you actually want to accomplish. The `F` interface doesn't really specify, which information flows from which method into whatever location at what time, so: this is still a best-guess efford.

Comment: I don't see how it generalizes to the problem in whole, that is, making `F` immutable. For that, I'll need to keep the data outside of each implementation of `F`.

Comment: I edited the question to include some skeleton code to illustrate what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: Either I don't understand your updated solution, or it's not purely functional: 
`def aggregate(s: String): Unit = origin.aggregate(origin.get(s), init)`
I still don't see how to make it purely functional.

Comment: By "purely functional", I mean "without storing data in each implementation of `F` and mutating it upon `aggregate`".

Comment: Your current answer is purely functional, but it works in one phase. I need to first aggregate the data reading through the lines, and then process while reading the lines again. In your case, when `F1.process` is called, `data` should be the number of lines. But as it is now, each `process` receives just the number of the current line.

Comment: @vuvuzela - Ah! But I think, in this case, you will have to temporarily wrap the values generated during the first phase into something, which provides a "concrete type agnostic" interface (akin to the `Op` class in my original proposal). In the first pass, you construct a sequence of `Op` instances, in the second pass, you consume them

Comment: @vuvuzela - how would you match the "string/aggregated value" pairs from the first pass during the second? What's the set-up of the loop in the second pass?

Comment: For each string, a function (`F`) takes the value it has aggregated during the first phase and this string and produces a new string.

For example: I need to normalize values. In the first phase, mean and standard deviation are computed, so for such a function, the datum is a pair of doubles. During the second phase, an int value is read from each string, and then normalized using the data (pair of doubles.) Strings come from a largish file, and I want to look at each string as little as I can.